# Ruby call php script with parameters

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, net-http, open-uri

I am trying to open and read output of php script it looks like:
domain.com/scripts/script.php?assetid=xxxxx&checksum=yyyy
when I open this in any browser it works fine.
So I tried to use open-uri gem to get output - returns code 200 no output.
I tried

```
Net::HTTP.post_form('domain.com/scripts/script.php', {'assetid'=>'xxxxx', 'checksum'=>'yyyy'})
```

without desired output.
Can you help me choose correct way to open and parse this uri ?

Comment: Why are you posting to that script? Isn't it supposed to be a GET request?

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting 200, you are getting your result.

```
uri = URI('http://example.com/index.html')
params = { :limit => 10, :page => 3 }
uri.query = URI.encode_www_form(params)

res = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
puts res.body if res.is_a?(Net::HTTPSuccess)
```

This straight from [ruby documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html)

If you are doing web scraping, you will want to use the ruby gem`Mechanize`.